# How to call function pointer which is passed to Mock method?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

```
virtual void doSomething(std::function<void(std::error_code result)> callback) = 0

MockMethod1(doSomething, std::function<void(std::error_code result)> callback);
```

Now when I write EXPECT_CALL, how can I call "callback"

```
EXPECT_CALL(object, doSomething(testing::_)).WillRepeatedly( ??? );
```

What should I write at to call my callback?

Comment: No feedback? Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to do custom action.

I found answer as different way,
here is what you need to do,

EXPECT_CALL(.....).WillRepeatedly(testing::InvokeArgument<1>(arg1, arg2, ..));

Answer (score 3):

Use custom actions to achieve this. To achieve more flexibility, I suggest creating a template for an action, where template parameter signifies argument index of the callback function in `doSomething`. Here is how you do this:

```
ACTION_TEMPLATE(ExecuteCallback, HAS_1_TEMPLATE_PARAMS(unsigned, uIndex), AND_1_VALUE_PARAMS(callbackArg))
{
    (std::get<uIndex>(args))(callbackArg);
}
```

Note that you can add more value parameters if needed. Now, in you test you call setup mock calls like this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(object, doSomething(testing::_)).WillRepeatedly(DoAll(ExecuteCallback<0>(err), Return()));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great too

Comment: @user2317738 You're welcome! Consider upvoting the answer if you think it is a useful alternative. Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks @Marko, upvoted ...internally InvokeArgument use the same thing which you described.